# Grid items: automatic vs defined placement

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I had a question regarding the `display:grid` property, specifically when it comes to two-column layouts. In the snippet I've set up a basic two-col. layout.  When you have something like this, just a `2fr` section and a `1fr` section do you still need to assign where the column begins and spans like `grid-column: 1/2;` or is it simply implicit?

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 17px;
}

main {
  width: 1080px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 500px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;
  grid-rows: auto;
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

article {
  border: 1px solid;
  //grid-column: 1/2;
}

.sidebar {
  border: 1px solid;
  //grid-column: 2/3;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <article></article>
  <aside class="sidebar"></aside>
</main>
```

Comment: It's implicit..assuming I understand your question correctly. See - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/xXEYpK

Comment: @Paulie_D I think you do. I also think I made a booboo, a 2col layout would have 6 sections to span not 2 right? So col = 1/2...grid gap=3/4...sidebar = 5/6 correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CSS Grid Layout has something called the [**Grid Item Placement Algorithm**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#auto-placement-algo).

This algorithm defines a process for laying out grid items based on various factors.

For example, source order matters. You have a two-column grid and two grid items, and the [**`order`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#order-modified-document-order) property isn't in play, so the items are laid out in their order of appearance in the HTML.

Also, the initial setting of the [**`grid-auto-flow`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#grid-auto-flow-property) property is `row`. This means that grid items are rendered horizontally, by default. If you change the value to `column` or `dense`, the layout changes.

For a complete explanation and a list of factors taken into consideration see:

> [**8.5. Grid Item Placement
>   Algorithm**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#auto-placement-algo)
>
> The following grid item placement algorithm resolves automatic
>   positions of grid items into definite positions, ensuring that every
>   grid item has a well-defined grid area to lay out into.

Comment: In the two col layout I made above there are technically three columns because of the start and end of the grid gap. If I was to write out the column span for each of them do I need to include the space taken up by the column gap? So for example col. 1 should span 1/2 and column 2 should span 5/6 because the gap is taking up 3/4

Comment: *In the two col layout I made above there are technically three columns because of the start and end of the grid gap.* No. There are technically only two columns.

Comment: A column is created by two adjacent vertical grid lines. The width of each column is the distance between these two lines. The `grip-gap` property essentially defines the width of the grid line. The width of each line can be ignored when spanning columns. Test it out.